# How to find INPUT element in wpf Webbrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, input, webbrowser-control

Im trying to build an application where I use tabtip on every INPUT field in my webbrowser control. But I recently switched to WPF and in the old WinForms code I used 
`HtmlElement element = Browser.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition)`

In my new code i'm using a click event to determin the time on which im trying to open up tabtip but it only needs to happen when the clicked element is an INPUT field. My code:

```
public static void webBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e, WebBrowser browser)
{
    mshtml.HTMLDocument doc;
    doc = (mshtml.HTMLDocument)browser.Document;
    mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent;
    iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)doc;
    iEvent.onclick += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(ClickEventHandler);
}
```

And this is where I want to check if the clicked element is an input:

```
private static bool ClickEventHandler(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item Clicked"); //if(HtmlElement == INPUT) like scenario here
    return true;
}
```

I used [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95bc55b0-0f3f-44da-b560-5f8a08b0dcfd/how-do-i-know-what-element-is-clicked-in-a-wpf-webbrowser-control?forum=wpf) source but I have a hard time understanding their words since i'm trying to handle everything with xaml and c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static bool ClickEventHandler(mshtml.IHTMLEventObj e)
{
    mshtml.IHTMLInputElement inputElement = e.srcElement as mshtml.IHTMLInputElement;
    if (inputElement != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("<input> clicked");
    }
    return true;
}
```